# Angular- Material tags are not working properly

Tags: angular

everyone, I am new on Angular. I need to create a simple list using material angular. I got just a blank white web page instead of button. Below is my code

template file:

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item> Paprika </mat-list-item>
 </mat-list>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import {MaterialModule} from './material/material.module'
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,
    // MatSlideToggleModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatListModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check in your console if you have errors?

When you have a white page output, it's often becquse of some HTML error ( a tag not closed or similar). It can also be some imported module's error.
In both cases you will find a red error in console that will tell you exactly what's missing in your code to display your application properly.

With chrome you can do f12, click on console and check. Be shure to have errors enabled. [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3glS.png)